# His legacy is the rich promise of social reform

Tags: meaning-in-context

> GEORGE FLOYD was not famous. He was killed not in the capital of the United States, but on a street corner in its 46th-largest city. Yet in death he has suddenly become the keystone of a movement that has seized all of America. Still more remarkably, he has inspired protests abroad, from Brazil to Indonesia, and France to Australia. **His legacy is the rich promise of social reform**. It is too precious to waste.

---

What does "legacy" and "rich promise" mean?

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? If so, what sounds ambiguous to you?

Comment: **legacy** : money or property left to sb in a will ; **promise** : a statement that you will certainly do something. So the sentence means "the money he left is a lot of guarantee for  social reform"?.

Comment: Promise means a "sort of hope for a  better future of " and it has several meanings in different contexts. you may want to check all the entries for that word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The definition you cite in your comment is not great. "Legacy" usually refers primarily to *non-monetary* things that are left behind when someone passes away. When a composer passes away, he or she will leave a legacy of great music and influence on future composers, for example. A person might leave behind a legacy consisting of his children, the things he taught them, and their influence on the world. The founding fathers of the US left behind a legacy of freedom and democracy that would have an unparalleled influence on the world. It can also be used in a negative context. The practice of slavery, now dead, left behind a legacy of race-based class that still plagues us today.

In this case Floyd's legacy refers to the promise, meaning the likely possibility, of major social reform that he left us with.